# problem in st_contains postgis vie postgres

Tags: postgis

i am new in postgis and have a problem when using st_contains in postgressql.
i have two table :
one table with multilinestring type and srid 3857 like this :

> 'MULTILINESTRING((5422968.66785559 3677150.09505449,5422968.65492085
>   3677150.0886859,5422952.17411073 3677141.94577852,5422933.98180744 3677132.88239635,5422908.89206302 3677120.3831169,5422889.41793598 3677110.66168418,5422860.41342641 3677096.31330017,5422843.29303681 3677087.88278276),(5422968.4135149 3677150.59358815,5422980.01582934 3677156.57635076,5422990.22979481 3677161.61762274,5423006.30129137 3677169.56131558))'

and another table Points type and srid 3857 like this :

> 'POINT(48.6977500915527 31.3106079101563)'

i use from st_buffer for first table which is multilinestring geom type and expect find any point from table 2  that is inside this buffer

when i use st_contains does not return any row , what is the problem ? although both srid are 3857

```
select ST_X(P.geom) lng , ST_Y(P.geom) lat from public."Zone" A
inner join public."Points" P on ST_Contains(ST_Buffer(A.geom, 100), P.geom)
```

Answer (score 0):

From: 
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html

And

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html

It says that the geom inside st_X and st_Y must be a point, or NULL if not available.

Can you try just running

```
select A.geom as lines, P.geom as point from public."Zone" A
inner join public."Points" P on ST_Contains(ST_Buffer(A.geom, 100), P.geom);
```

To see if it returns anything ?

Comment: my problem is another thing : the point with format  'POINT(48.6977500915527 31.3106079101563)' can't be inside the buffer cus multilinestring point format is like 5422968.66785559  3677150.09505449

Comment: although both srid is  3857 !! 
what's my wrong ?? if i need change point format

Comment: Hey Hamed, that looks like a separate question, it would be best if you could open a new SO question for it, or search for previous cases like that.

If my previous answer solved the first question, could you give it an accept ? And you could refer your next question's url here so I could follow. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The point is not in 3857 but rather in 4326. You would need to transform it to 3857 first

```sql
select st_asText(st_transform(st_GeomFromText('POINT(48.6977500915527 31.3106079101563)',4326),3857));
                st_astext
------------------------------------------
 POINT(5421008.74296974 3673153.53251071)
```

That being said, it is more reliable to use `st_dwithin` rather than `st_buffer`.